# Order Strings as Times in Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I'm trying to order that contains timeslots as keys that are stroed as strings. The OrderBy linq query works for everything after to 10:00 entries before that are displayed after 23:59. For the code below 'dictionary' is a Dictionary object with a string as the key and custom object as the value.

```
Dim dictionary = existing.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Key).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Value)
```

How can I modify the sort to get the times out in the correct order?

Comment: Why is it a string if it should be a `TimeSpan`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I can just convert the Key to a DateTime object just to order it.

```
Dim dictionary = existing.OrderByDescending(Function(x) Convert.ToDateTime(x.Key)).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Value)
```